# Bootstrap Modal: make the whole columns clickable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am testing on this [website](http://cms.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/)  some modal windows and as you can see now the modals are toggled on click / touch on the play button.

My question is: is possible to make the whole columns clickable and make the modals open?

I tried to define also a data-toggle for the whole div with the data-target without any results.

This is the HTML code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<i class="fa fa-play btn btn-lg" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></i>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modal-video" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Title 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      <video controls="" width="100%" id="video">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      <div class="modal-text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn button-eh-magenta">Go to Shop</button>
    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn button-eh-magenta">Share</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an id for your div that you want on clicking on that open modal and do like this:

```
$('#specified_div').click(function(){
    $('#targetmodal').modal();
});
```

Another way is to  add `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#targetmodal"` to any element that you want by clicking on that element modal with id `targetmodal` open.

---

and Here is bootstrap site quote:

> **Via data attributes**
>
> Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set `data-toggle="modal"`
>   on a controller element, like a button, along with a
>   `data-target="#foo"` or `href="#foo"` to target a specific modal to
>   toggle.
>
> ```
> <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
> ```
>
> **Via JavaScript**
>
> Call a modal with id myModal with a single line of JavaScript:
>
> ```
> $('#myModal').modal(options)
> ```

Comment: Hi,

I already tried with assign data-toggle and data-target to a div but the results is that is not possible to close the modal.

Comment: No errors. You can have a look, I have applied for the first column the data-target and data-toggled as you suggested. It happens that the modal does not close.

http://cms.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/

Comment: move out your modal div from inner col-md-6 div https://codepen.io/poursadeqi/pen/qjwGqG?editors=1010 where is your code that I pulled out your code from inner divs and set data attributes on div and it work correctly (of course I just set it for red div :D @Roxana)